# Understanding Python nested function sample

Tags: python

[This link](https://stackabuse.com/python-nested-functions/#:%7E:text=An%20inner%20function%20is%20simply,but%20it%20cannot%20change%20them.) talks about Python nested functions.

They have this example:

```
def num1(x):
   def num2(y):
      return x * y
   return num2
res = num1(10)

print(res(5))
```

When I run it, it multiplies 10 by 5 and prints out 50. How does it "run"

```
res = num1(10)
```

... if the `num1()` function is only given a single argument of 10? `y` is not defined when `num1(10)` is run. The print function only executes when it runs `res(5)`, but how are you "stuffing" two values into `x` in the parent function?

I'm thinking there's a bigger picture thing I'm not understanding in relation to how the function and order is running.

Thanks for looking at this beginner question. I'm just trying to understand... baby steps.

Comment: Edit: Thanks guys! Very easy for a beginner to understand.

Comment: The *key point* to understand is that *functions are just objects like any other*, just like `int`, `str`, `list`, `dict` etc, they can be created inside a function, and returned from that function, and you can assign functions to whatever variables you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `res = num1(10)` it assigns a function to res, but doesn't run it.

You can kind of think of it like this (not valid syntax, only for illustration):

```
res = def num2(y):
        return 10 * y
```

Then when you call `res`, it actually runs the function and does the multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

You supply `y` when you do `res(5)`; `y` isn't given a value when `num1` is run.

`num1` returns a function that will require `y`. `y` is supplied when that returned function is called.

This is a common technique to delay the need for supplying information to a function. If a function accepts two parameters but you only have one of the arguments handy, you can return a function that wraps a call to the function where the known parameter already passed. You're left with a function that accepts the remaining data when it becomes available.